# Setting width of table inside another table is not reflecting in created pdf

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

Below is the code which i am using. I want a table with width 40, & inside that table, there is another table with width 25. Whatever value i give to inner table, it seems to have a fixed width. It tried with different options like 'LockedWidth', but that makes the table super small. Could please anyone help in that.

```
PdfPTable outerTable = new PdfPTable(1) { HorizontalAlignment = 0 };
outerTable.TotalWidth = 40;
PdfPCell outerTableColumn = new PdfPCell()
{
    FixedHeight = 20,
    BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(217, 83, 79)
};

PdfPTable innerTable = new PdfPTable(1) { HorizontalAlignment = 0 };
innerTable.TotalWidth = 28;
PdfPCell innerTableColumn = new PdfPCell()
{
    FixedHeight = 15,
    BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(92, 184, 92)
};
innerTable.AddCell(innerTableColumn);
outerTableColumn.AddElement(innerTable);
outerTable.AddCell(outerTableColumn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't try it right now, but I think this should help:

```
innerTable.WidthPercentage = 62.5f;
```